# Keeping tokens that shorter than minLength in ngram filter (ElasticSearch)

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there anyway to keep the tokens that shorter than minLength of ngram in ElasticSearch?

For example:
The data is "abc x" ==> ngram(2,4) will generate tokens: ab, bc, abc. 
"x" was removed because its length < 2 (minLength).

I want to keep "x" because it still a keyword in original data.

What filters I need to use in order to keep it (using ES 0.90) ?

Is it good if ngram filter have an option to keep shorter tokens like in this case?

Comment: i think that all your data is still stored in the magic ALL field unless you tell elasticsearch not to do so explicitly. that way you can always query the ALL field for direct matches.

Comment: Yes it can be done by using multi_field. But it's more effective if we can define an analyzer to do that, and we can query data base on just one field, instead of multi_field or ALL field.